# How can I return a synchronous reply from an asynchronous method?

Tags: angularjs

I have a method that I use to get data from my web server:

```
getUserTestQuestions = (testId): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    var defer = this.$q.defer();
    this.$http({
        url: '/api/UserTestQuestion/GetAll/' + testId,
        method: "GET"
    })
        .success(function (data: IUserTestQuestion[]) {
            self.qs = data;
            defer.resolve();
        })
        .error((data: any, status: number, headers: (headerName: string) => string, config: ng.IRequestConfig): void => {
            self.$ers.http(data, status, headers, config);
            defer.reject();
        })
    return defer.promise;
}
```

It returns a promise which is used by the caller.

I would like to modify this so that it only returns data from the web server if the data is not already present. To do this I am thinking to add a check like this:

```
getUserTestQuestions = (testId): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    var defer = this.$q.defer();

    if ( question.downloaded ) {
        defer.resolve(); // I am doing a resolve here but is it the correct way
                         // as I think it will happen before the defer.promise 
                         // is returned?
    } else {

      this.$http({
          url: '/api/UserTestQuestion/GetAll/' + testId,
          method: "GET"
      })
        .success(function (data: IUserTestQuestion[]) {
            self.qs = data;
            defer.resolve();
        })
        .error((data: any, status: number, headers: (headerName: string) => string, config: ng.IRequestConfig): void => {
            self.$ers.http(data, status, headers, config);
            defer.reject();
        })
    }
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Is this a valid way to be doing this? It seems odd to return immediately with a resolve when I am not actually doing anything asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `$q.when` if you want to return promise if data already exist

```
getUserTestQuestions = (testId): ng.IPromise<any> => {

    if ( question.downloaded ) {
        return $q.when(data) // I am doing a resolve here but is it the correct way
                         // as I think it will happen before the defer.promise 
                         // is returned?
    } else {

    var self = this;
    var defer = this.$q.defer();

     this.$http({
          url: '/api/UserTestQuestion/GetAll/' + testId,
          method: "GET"
      })
        .success(function (data: IUserTestQuestion[]) {
            self.qs = data;
            defer.resolve();
        })
        .error((data: any, status: number, headers: (headerName: string) => string, config: ng.IRequestConfig): void => {
            self.$ers.http(data, status, headers, config);
            defer.reject();
        })
    return defer.promise;
    }
}
```

this way the caller can always do

```
getUseTestQuestion(testId).then()
```

note that the `$q.when` return the output / existing data

Comment: I use it lot, for maintaining static data, once fetched from db. The advantage is, your calling method wont know if the data case from db or from memory... so they agnostic of how the $resource is implemented or used...